# Eclipse: annoying arrows inside code editor

Tags: eclipse

I have a small problem with eclipse. 
When I write my code, I have some annoying arrows in the left side of the line and another unexplained symbol at the end of each line.

Unfortunately, I cannot post an image because I'm new here...
Do you know how to cancel these?

Comment: For better understanding post the screen shot here http://postimg.org/ and share the link

Answer (score 1):

These are most likely the whitespace markers.

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors

Uncheck "show whitespace characters".